# Visual Studio Crashes while opening cordova project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I created a blank app, saved, added a bower file from a project i want to merge in and then closed visual studio.  Now I can't even open the project or Visual studio crashes.  Anyone else running into this with CTP3?

Comment: Where/how did you add the bower file?

Comment: Copy pasted it into the project root from another project.  I tried removing it (including the reference in the project file), but the project keeps crashing so I just had to delete it to get my solution to open.  If context helps, I am trying to migrate an ionic app I have in an empty project template (just included files that npm/ionic built for their templates in the project) into the cordova project.

Comment: Same problem here. Visual Studio can't even open the cordova project. And if I install it on the device using 'cordova run windows --device -- --phone' the application is installed but crashes immediately on open. This works flawlessly on both iOS and Android. Working with Cordova on Windows has been nothing less than a nightmare.